# Aligning Image to center

Tags: css, image, alignment, containers

Having difficulty in getting the three images to be bottom center of the respective box/containers, without spilling over the edges of onto the yellow background. The web address [link](http://www.tigzcreative.co.uk)

[image: Snapshot of images I am trying to centre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove height

```
.feedback-box .client {
    margin-top: 30px;
/*  height: 73px; */
    position: relative;
}
```

Remove Float, 
add margin: 0 auto;

```
.feedback-box .client-image {
    /*  float: right; */
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 4px solid #ececec;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `float` and add `margin: 0 auto` to `.client-image` class:

```
.feedback-box .client-image {
    /*  float: right; Remove this or float:none */ 
    width: 150px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 4px solid #ececec;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and add `margin-bottom` into `.feedback-box .client`

```
.feedback-box .client {
    margin-top: 30px;
    height: 73px;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```